# What exercises are best for keeping firm/nonsaggy pectorals?

Tags: upper-body-workout

I always remember the nature boy rick flair when I was a young kid and his old man saggy chest...  Now i'm getting older and that image bugs me some (so does the mirror).

I'm assuming certain types of push-up positions are better than others for keeping pec's fit and firm.  What are they?

Comment: I heard Charles Poliquin recommend supplementing with Gotu Kola a few months ago for minimizing loose skin (not fat).  My wife started taking it for post-giant-baby stretch marks, and after a few months they've almost completely gone away.  I'm not hocking supplements, but it might be worth looking into for your Nature Boy sag ;).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I gotta find a solution before I get too much older.  Time to let this adventure begin.

Comment: A Rick Flair and a subtle Remo Williams reference both in the same post?  Are you me from the future (if so, you'll know exactly how many "jiggawatts" it will take to bring you back).

Comment: I can't continue, my lunch was at 1:21 and I've got to get back to work.